# undefined variable in laravel 10 when try to routes

Tags: laravel

i try to create qr viewer which is collecting text from databases, and show it as a Qr code. but it's always get me an error where qr_codes not defined

this my controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\http\Requests;

class QrCodeController extends Controller{
    public function index(){
        $qr_codes = DB::select('select * from qr_code');
        return view ('QRcodeviewer',['qr_code'=>$qr_codes]);
    }
}
```

and here my blade view code

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')
    @section('content')
        <div class="container mt-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h2>QR Absen</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    {{ QrCode::size(300)->generate(Route('QRCodeviewer',$qr_codes->uuid)) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endsection
```

and this my routes

```
Route::get('QRcodeviewer','QrCodeController@index');
```

[error message]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvKJT.png

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your spelling error.

In your controller you set qr_code without s

```
return view ('QRcodeviewer',['qr_code'=>$qr_codes]);
```

but in view blade you try to access using $qr_codes,
try change to

```
{{ QrCode::size(300)->generate(Route('QRCodeviewer',$qr_code->uuid)) }}
```

Comment: it still get me an error with same message

Comment: We usually don't answer questions caused by typos but vote to close/flag instead. These questions are of no real use to anybody else

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
$qr_code = DB::table('qr_code')->first();
return view ('QRcodeviewer',['qr_code'=> $qr_code]);
```

In your view:

```
 {{ QrCode::size(300)->generate(Route('QRCodeviewer',$qr_code->uuid)) }}
```